# What is a field?

Tags: field-theory

What is a field? Lengthy texts about fields have been published but none ever answer the simple question "What do you mean when you say the world field."

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BK166SL-ig

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field

Comment: I sense some very strange phenomenon to be happening here.